# Bokeh: Use 2 Interactive Widgets to Filter Dataset with CustomJS

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I want to filter my data based on the values from the 2 Select widgets, where `source['level'] == level` and `source['country'] == country`.

Using CustomJS, I was able to get the `level` filter working using `cb_obj`.

But `cb_obj` only references the widget that triggered it. How do I get the value of the other select widget in the callback function?

I also need to stick to CustomJS, thanks!

Sample code:

```
# Level
level = Select(title="Level:", value='All Levels', options=['All Levels', '1', '2', '3'], callback=callback)

# Country
country = Select(title="Country:", value='All Countries', options=['All Countries', 'US', 'UK', 'CAN'], callback=callback)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ts=true_source), code="""
    var df = source.data;
    var data = ts.data;
    var data_level = data['Level'];

    var l=cb_obj.value;

    var data_x = data['x'];
    var data_y = data['y'];

    var x=[];
    var y=[];

    for (var i=0;i<data_level.length; i++){

        // Here: I want to add (Level) and (Country) filters
        // But I'm not sure how to reference Country widget value
        if(l=='All Levels' || data_level[i]==l){
            x.push(data_x[i]);
            y.push(data_y[i]);}}

    df['x'] = [];
    df['y'] = [];

    df['x'] = x;
    df['y'] = y;

    source.change.emit();
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass explicitly both `Select` widgets to the callback like this:

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source = source, 
                              ts = true_source, 
                              level = level,
                              country = country), code=code)
```

Then instead of `cb_obj.value` you get the values using: `level.value` and `country.value`